# How to scale from right to left in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate scale a div element. But the animation starts from the center and spreads. Is it there a way animation to start from right and spread to left?

```
.graybox {
  float: right;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: main 250ms;
  -moz-animation: main 250ms;
  -ms-animation: main 250ms;
  animation: main 250ms;
}

@-moz-keyframes main {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is `50% 50%`, you can reset that to `100% 50%`, the first value `100%` is x-offset, and the second value `50%` is y-offset.

To make the div to scale for both width and height, simply change `scaleX` to `scale`.

You also need to set the correct `@keyframes` syntax, `-moz` prefix will only work on Mozilla browsers like Firefox. I suggest to use [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) for adding popular prefixes.

```css
.graybox {
  float: right;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  animation: main 3s;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

@keyframes main {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="graybox"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `transform-origin`

```css
.graybox {
  float: right;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 100px;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  animation: main .5s;
}

@keyframes main {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="graybox"></div>
```

Comment: Thanx allot. Can you tell me from where i can read more about css animation, scale and those kind of stuff? Could you please give me some links ?